# Transactional Replication Subscriber Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

I have been doing database work for years but have very limited experience with replication.

When using Transactional Replication, is there any reason the subscriber needs to be in Full recovery mode? I've inherited several databases that are being replicated and all the subscribers are set to Full causing extremely large t-logs. I would like to set them to simple but am concerned that I could cause a production issue with the replication by doing so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, test before proceeding...

Replication does not require full recovery mode - the log reader agant will parse the transaction log and copy any transactions marked for replication to the publication DB.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706(SQL.105).aspx